# Pass a pointer using Qt signals and slots

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

So I have the following function:

```
void parseData()
{
    // DownloadManager and Post subclass QObject
    DownloadManager* downloadManager = new DownloadManager();
    Post* post = new Post(mPostsModel);

    // using qt signal and slots I would like to retrieve the Post in the onFileDownloaded slot
    connect(downloadManager, &DownloadManager::allDownloadsFinished, this, &MediaFetcher::onFileDownloaded);

}
```

Now I would like to get to my `Post* post` in my `MediaFetcher::onFileDownloaded` slot, something like this:

```
void MediaFetcher::onFileDownloaded()
{
    qDebug() << "files downloaded";
    DownloadManager* downloadManager = qobject_cast<DownloadManager*>(sender());
    Post* post = getPost(); // how do I get this???
    mPostsModel->append(post);

    downloadManager->deleteLater();
}
```

One solution that I think is very ugly (also I think it causes a memory leak) was to use [QObject::setProperty](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setProperty) and then add my `Post*` to the `downloadManager` and then get that in the slot (I had use `qvariant_cast`). In `parseData()`

```
    QVariant postVariant = QVariant::fromValue(post);
    downloadManager->setProperty("post", postVariant);
```

Then in `onFilesDownloaded()`:

```
    Post* post = qvariant_cast<Post*>(downloadManager->property("post"));
```

Does anyone know how can this be done in a more elegant way?

Comment: What if you make `Post* post` your `MediaFetcher` class' member variable?

Comment: Why not send a `Post` object (or const ref) via the signal to the slot?

Comment: @vahancho the problem would be that if the user calls `parseData()` another time, then the `Post*` might get set before the download is finished (hence the last `Post*` will be added).

Comment: @daljit97, but the same will happen with the download manager too, no?

Comment: @vahancho well the download manager is being created on the fly so there each call of `parseData()` creates a new one

Comment: @daljit97, another option is incapsulation of `Post` in `DownloadManager`, or storing mapping between Post and corresponding download manager: `std::map<DownloadManager *, Post *> m_map;` as a class member.

Comment: Using a map is interesting, but then I suppose I have to add additional code to manage the removal/addition of the managers and posts.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do this requires either to change the signature of your `allDownloadsFinished` signal to pass a `Post`:

```
class downloadManager : public QWidget
{
// Normal constructors and destructor and macros

signals:
   void allDownloadsFinished(Post* post);

};
```

or to add a new signal to `downloadManager` to be able to send `Post*`. In any case, you'll have to register the `Post` meta-type:

```
qRegisterMetaType<Post*>("Post*");
```

Obviously, this requires your slot to accept the `Post*` type.

Comment: Is `qRegisterMetaType` really required?

Comment: I think so. But you can try without. I normally put it in the constructor of the class to be sent.

Comment: Another question, in the `downloadManager` to emit the signal how do you "create" the `Post*` to be emitted? Is it create on the fly inside the class?

Comment: you have to do `emit allDownloadsFinished(post)` and that's it.

Comment: @daljit97 if it worked please, accept this as an answer.

Comment: I understand that I can simply emit a signal, but I would like to know is where the `post` is coming from? Going back to my example, in my `parseData()` function I create the `DownloadManager` and then I create my `Post*`. I can't just simply emit the signal with the post as a parameter as the signal will be emitted when the download is finished (not predictable at compile time). For your suggestion to work, the `Post*` must be created inside the `DownloadManager` class, am I correct?

Comment: As a side comment, if you are worried about memory leaks, you should probably consider using QSharedPointer<Post>, and let Qt manage the pointed memory.

Comment: You can send a signal with multiple arguments, you could send both the post and the download manager pointers (or smart pointers).

Comment: No, you don't need to register raw pointers as qMetaTypes